# Review Api for magento 2.1.12

Tags: magento-2.1, review, rest-api

I have successfully install this module [Reviews/Rating](https://github.com/ajay-ipragmatech/magento2)
I call this `url="/V1/review/mine/post" method="POST"`.I don't know what data is passed in body of this URL.

Comment: can you share all the files of your program

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151257)

Comment: I face the same problem plz tell me what i do now.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the module code `etc/webapi.xml` you will see following code

```
<route url="/V1/review/mine/post" method="POST">
    <service class="Ipragmatech\Ipreview\Api\ReviewInterface" method="writeReviews"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self" />
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="customer_id" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
```

And API signature in `\Ipreview\Api\ReviewInterface`

```
 /**
     * Added review and rating for the product.
     * @param int $productId
     * @param string $title
     * @param string $nickname
     * @param string $detail
     * @param Ipragmatech\Ipreview\Api\Data\RatingInterface[] $ratingData
     * @param int $customer_id
     * @param int $store_id
     * @return boolean
     *
     */
    public function writeReviews(
        $productId,
        $nickname,
        $title,
        $detail,
        $ratingData,
        $customer_id = null,
        $storeId
    );
```

So whenever you are setting  **ref** as **self** the data will be taken from the token passed as **bearer token** and data node below it specify which data has to be taken form the the token . In above case it is customer ID , it also can be token .
$customer_id will be taken from token and rest of the params can be passed in below body format

```
{
            "productId": "10",
            "nickname": "Mann",
            "title": "Cool, Nice product",
            "detail": "This is nice product. I recommended this product.",
            "ratingData": [{
                "rating_id": "3",
                "ratingCode": "price",
                "ratingValue": "5"
            }, {
                "rating_id": "4",
                "ratingCode": "Rating",
                "ratingValue": "2"
            }],
            "storeId": "1"
         }
```

Comment: I  will pass this data as following: {"productId":"8","nickname":"lovely","title":"Nice Product","detail":"This is nice product","ratingData":[{"ratingValue":"2"}],"storeId":"1"}.But its showing error :[{"status":false,"message":"We can't post your review right now. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'value' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `rating_option_vote` (`option_id`, `review_id`, `percent`, `value`, `remote_ip`, `remote_ip_long`, `customer_id`, `entity_pk_value`, `rating_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"}].

Comment: @LovelySetia updated the answer , Please accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: it is throwing the same error for me too, what code changes needs to be done?

Comment: is that plugin is support for the Magento 2.3.0